# Login to PowerApps using Sharepoint Credentials

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have created a PowerApps and now I want to login using SharePoint credentials.

I used this formula on onSelect of login button
`If(LookUp('Account Name', Title = Username.Text, Password ) = Password, Navigate([@Screen1], ScreenTransition.Fade))`

Here **Account Name** is my DataSource , **Title** and **Password** are columns in DataSource.

So how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand your question properly.

You have a SharePoint List of something like below.

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSXkQ.jpg)

And a login page like this

[loginpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj9Wh.jpg)

on click on Signin button you want to verify Account and password exists in the list and let the user navigate to a welcome page.

Assuming the above scenario is what you want, the onSelect would look like this:

If((LookUp(**'list-test'**,**AccountName** = **TextInput1**.Text).**Password** = **TextInput3**.Text), Set(**errorMessage**, "");Navigate(**Screen2**,ScreenTransition.Fade), Set(**errorMessage**, "Wrong account name or password"))

- **'list-test'** - will be replaced by your datasource name
- **AccountName** - will be replaced with whatever column name in sharepoint list that contains the account title
- **TextInput1** - will be replaced with the name of the TextInput that will contain the account name in login page
- **Password** - will be replaced with the name of the column in sharepoint list that contains the passwords
- **TextInput3** - will be replaced with the name of the TextInput that will contain the user Input password
- **errorMessage** - this is a global variable I set to display an error message in case of failure
- **Screen2** - will be the screen that you will take user to after successful check

In my example I have a label (label3) whose text is bound to that global variable **errorMessage** in case of error.